# POST method is not working while clicking on the menu option in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to build a menu for my website. When I click on the menu it is supposed to POST to index.php but nothing is happening. I have checked using console.log, the values assign to data-val in  are coming in but the hidden INPUT is not working. Can someone put in the right direction by pointing out the problem. Thanks

Here is JQuery

```
       $(document).ready(function($) {
           $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
               $('#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
           });
       });
```

here is the HTML

```
    <form name="mainmenu" id="mainmenu" method="post" action="index.php">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="96%" height="50" background="images/headerPanel.jpg" valign="center">
                <font face="verdana" size="1" color="white"> <h1 align="center">ABC Company</h1></font>
            </td>
            <td width="3%" background="images/headerPanel.jpg" valign="center" align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout" />
            </td>
            <td width="1%" background="images/headerPanel.jpg" valign="center"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="2%" bgColor=#C11B17></td>
            <td width="16%" bgColor=#C11B17>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Maintanence</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="1-1">Add Category</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="1-2">Add Sub-category</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Process Order</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="2-1">Ship Order</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="2-2">Change Order Status</a></li>        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="3-1">Orders by station</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="3-2">Orders by date</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-val="3-3">Pending Orders</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <input id="shareto" type="hidden" name="shareto">
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Add $('#mainmenu').submit(); after $('#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));

Comment: You are not submitting the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem you submit button of form used for logout, if you need use submit button for logout, then for send menu item index you need use ajax query and not needed  "shareto" input element. Afterwards in server side you can redirect correct menu page. Or vice versa.

Here is full code: 
client side js file:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
        var menuItemIndex = $(this).data('val');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType:'json',
          url: "index.php",
          data: {
               menuindex: JSON.stringify(menuItemIndex)
          },
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              console.log(data.menu_location);
              window.location = data.menu_location;
          },
          error: function(errorMsg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              console.log(errorMsg);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });
     });
});
```

Server side index.php :

```
<?php
     $menu_locations = array("1-1" => "URL_1.html", "1-2" => "URL2_.html");
     $menu_item_index = json_decode($_POST['menuindex']);

     header("Content-type: application/json");
     echo json_encode(array("menu_location" => $menu_locations[$menu_item_index]));
```

Comment: It worked as far as the POST is concerns but nothing is there in index.php. $_POST is showing empty array

Comment: @bipen the solution from mr.boybox worked. console is showing the value clicked but POST is empty, nothing is getting there. Any comments

Answer (score 0):

you need to submit the form to post the data... use jquery s[ubmit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to submit the form..

try this

```
   $(document).ready(function($) {
       $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
           $('#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
           $('#mainmenu').submit();
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery needs to be:

```
   $(document).ready(function($) {
       $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
           $('#shareto').val($(this).data('val'));
           $('#mainmenu').submit();
       });
   });
```